# Can't make taps gem 0.3.23 working with heroku gem 2.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, heroku

Anyone have an fix for this problem?

It happens on push and pull.

```
~ heroku db:push
Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- taps/operation
You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
On most systems this will be:

sudo gem install taps
~ sudo gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.13)
mime-types (1.16)
rack (1.2.2)
rake (0.9.0)
rest-client (1.6.1)
sequel (3.20.0)
sinatra (1.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
taps (0.3.23)
~
~ heroku version
heroku-gem/2.1.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Bundler, you can try to declare in `gem "taps"` into your Gemfile. 
Currently i am using:

```
taps (0.3.23)
heroku (2.6.1)
```

working with

```
rails (3.1.0.rc5)
rack (1.3.2)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I solved the problem by adding taps to my Gemfile and using `bundle exec heroku db:push`

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading rack version to 1.0.1